# Installing Python Packages: Missing Directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to install some python packages and can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. I'm getting the following error when I run ez_install:

```
$ easy_install scipy
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the installation directory:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/blackbird/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-5544.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or the distutils default setting) was:

/Users/blackbird/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir option).
```

I've gone into my library, and the Python folder doesn't exist. Obviously I could just create it manually, but does this indicate that I'm doing something else wrong or that I'm missing something?

Comment: You should use `pip`, not `easy_install`.

Comment: @simeon-visser When I try and install pip, I get the same error. I can't install any packages.

Comment: Did you try to install pip using easy_install? It should be installed using the get-pip.py file.

Comment: Please read official tutorial how to install Python packages - you should never install them over your system-wide Python installation: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/projects.html#virtualenv